# How to remove map's fog of war in Grim Dawn

Tags: grim-dawn

Just installed Grim Dawn to give it a try years after TQ and noticed that every time the player continues his journey, the map is revealed but the areas still have fog of war in mini-map and quest points (stars) and NPCs cannot be seen unless the player goes there again. Is there a config option or some map-hack that removes this? Thanks in advance